# Date is not formatted in View when using DisplayFormat

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an example class `Student` with a formatted property of `DateTime?` type to display date only as `dd/MM/yyyy`. The snippet code is below:

```
public partial class Student
{
    // ...
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(StudentMetaData))]
public partial class Student
{
}

public class StudentMetaData
{
    // ...
    [DisplayFormat(
        DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", 
        ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, 
        NullDisplayText="Date's not provided")]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

I send all students in collection `List<Student>` as a model to a view and read through the records but the `Date` property is not formatted as I want. Also, it does not provide the text when a date in a particular field is missing. Is there any other attribute I'd have to set? This is the code in a view:

```
@using MvcDbContext.Models
@model List<Student>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of Students";
}
<h2>List of Students</h2>
<table>
    @foreach (Student student in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @student.StudentName
            </td>
            <td>
                @student.Gender
            </td>
            <td>
                @student.Date
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

and this is the output:

```
Adam     Male    07/05/2012 00:00:00  <- Date's not been formatted
Alex     Female  09/11/2014 00:00:00
Angela   Female  24/12/2011 00:00:00
Chris    Male                         <- here's supposed to be info "Date's not provided"
Clint    Male                         <- here's supposed to be info "Date's not provided"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you output like that you essentially are doing a `ToString()` on the value. Instead use the Html helpers:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => student.Date)
```